# Working with both Visual Studio 2008 and 2013 using TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Some of my colleagues use Visual Studio 2008, while others, including myself are on 2013.  Almost all of the solutions in Team Foundation Server were created using Visual Studio 2008.

The problem arises when I open a Visual Studio 2008 solution.  It forces me to perform a one-way upgrade, thus checking out the solution file.  At that point, the users on Visual Studio 2008 are unable to open the solution.

Is there any workaround to opening source controlled solution files in a newer version while still allowing my colleagues on 2008 to work with the solution?  Are we using TFS incorrectly?  Should we not be checking in the solution and project files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a visual studio issue, not TFS. What you are wanting is called project round tripping which wasn't available until Visual Studio 2010. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/05/visual-studio-2012-compatibility-aka-project-round-tripping.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Mike Cheel indicated, you'll get what you want if your colleagues can upgrade from VS 2008 to VS 2010 or later.

Alternatively, you'll need to create two separate sets of solution and project files -- one to use for VS 2008 and one to use for 2010+. I wouldn't recommend it though, due to the double maintenance.

And yes, you definitely should have your solution and project files under source control!

Comment: Also, there are .net version issues as visual studio 2008 doesn't support the same level of framework as 2010 and higher (same thig with 2010, doesn't support 4.5).